# Validating XHTML5 in PHP?

Tags: php, domdocument, xml-validation, relaxng, html

### Background

 I have made the decision to serve my website as `application/xhtml+xml` to anyone who will accept it.  I understand that there are consequences, which consequences I'm willing to accept.

### Problem

 I'm trying to validate XHTML5 in PHP.  That way, I can serve the file as `text/html` if validation fails (hey, ain't nobody perfect).  My question has merit even when taken outside of my situation, though.

**So how what are my options to validate XHTML5?**

---

**What I've done:**

I'm already using PHP's `DOMDocument` in my source code as a form of templating, so I'd like to be able to use [DOMDocument::relaxNGValidate](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.relaxngvalidate.php) or [DOMDocument::schemaValidate](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.schemavalidate.php).  I can find neither `.xsd` nor `.rng` to use.  However, I think I have found a [directory to make an rng grammar](http://syntax.whattf.org/relaxng/) out of.  Before today, I'd never even heard of Relax NG.  Any help on this direction?

Comment: In hindsight I was hasty and you are correct to have rolled it back. Sorry for the hassle.

Comment: What about taking a look at w3c validator source code http://validator.w3.org/source, not sure if it can help.

Comment: At least you should know, what _you_ produce, so in my eyes such a validation process is only interesting for testing (before release and such).

Comment: @KingCrunch If I produce code that breaks XML, the client would simply break when I send it `application/xhtml+xml`.  That's not very good.  Serving them `text/html` tag soup is much better. Hence the automatic validation.  We do have some (very little) user-submitted content, and this primarily affects this section.

Comment: It sounds to me as though you simply need to ensure XML is valid XML so that, if it isn't, you'll instead send it as `text/html`. Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: @KevinPeno Ideally it would be valid XML based on a schema.  But as far as being practical, that would probably work.

Comment: The problem is there will likely never be a sanctioned XHTML5 schema because HTML, as of HTML5, is no longer SGML and XHTML, as defined by HTML5, is not XML. It only contains provisions for the allowance of XML serialization. If you take that with your willingness to present tag soup if it fails validation, you are technically only checking for XML validity in order to ensure that you can present the content as XML (or XHTML) via mime so validity of the `DOCTYPE` or HTML version doesn't really matter here. I'd simply check it is valid XML and move on.

Comment: @KevinPeno The official HTML5 validator uses schema - how would they validate the code without something to validate against.

However, if you present browsers with well-formed but invalid XHTML5, they will still render it (so-called "draconian" error-handling only applies to non-well-formed XML, not to invalid XHTML), so purely from a server-side overhead point of view validating to a schema might be overkill.

Comment: @lucideer  you realize that the spec and validation have come a long way since November of last year.

Comment: @KevinPeno Not sure what you mean. The HTML5 validator has been around since before 2007 if that's what you're talking about http://blog.whatwg.org/validatornu-web-service-api

Answer (score 2):

As @Kevin Peno pointed out, HTML5 is not XML, and although that initially rubbed me the wrong way, I've come to terms with it and decided to treat HTML5 as a final output format only, instead of a document with the potential to be re-used and transformed again via XML tools.

My suggestion, if you wish to go down this path, is to pass your HTML5 markup through a cleanup process that guarantees valid XML (tools such as Tidy come to mind).

Your other option is to re-think your approach a bit and treat the HTML as a final output format. Use a different markup language to store content, and possibly even structure of your website.

For example, you could use Markdown for content (easily converted to HTML). If you prefer to stick with XML, perhaps define your own DSL, or re-use one such as [Simplified DocBook](http://www.docbook.org/specs/cs-docbook-simple-1.1.html). That has worked well for me in the past.

Then leverage XSL to transform your XML mash-up into HTML5, or any output format that you please.

Now, to try to answer your question directly, you will definitely need to "tidy" up the HTML5 markup to be sure it is valid XML before using a validation tool such as RelaxNG or XML Schema. As for your RNG schema file, I would suggest looking for an XHTML 1.0 Strict .rng first, and then perusing the HTML5 spec and adding elements and attributes as needed. A quick google search turned up [the following](http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/xhtml/).

*In case you're deciding between RNG and XML Schema, save yourself some headaches and go RelaxNG. This is my opinion, but I've used both extensively and RelaxNG is so much more human-readable and easier to work with!*

Answer (score 2):

The [new (Nu) HTML5 Validator](http://validator.nu/) has RELAX NG schema for various presets including XHTML5

See <del>https://bitbucket.org/validator/syntax/src/ed90a83ab0fd/relaxng</del> https://github.com/validator/validator/tree/master/syntax/relaxng

Is this what you're looking for or am I confused?